# Is there a fast way to interpose a character between strings?

Tags: c, linux, string

I wrote this function that will generate a single string out of a file list.
(e.g. if I have a folder with `FileA.txt`, `FileB.png` and `FileC` I'll get as output this string: `FileA.txtFileB.pngFileC`). Now I want to add a `/` character between each filename. (e.g. `FileA.txt/FileB.png/FileC/`) Is there a way to do it in "one blow" without having to repeat the same operation twice?

In other words, is there a way to do something like:

```
original_string = append2(original_string, new_string, '/');
```

instead of having to do

```
append(original_string, new_string);
append(original_string, "/");
```

?

Here's the function I wrote as reference:

```
/**
 * @brief Concatenate all file names in a file list (putting a '/' between each of them)
 * @param file_list The file list to serialize.
 * @return          A string containing all files in the file list.
 */
char *file_list_tostring(struct file_list *file_list) {
    char *final_string = NULL;
    size_t final_len = 0;
    struct file_node *list_iter = file_list->first;
    while (list_iter != NULL) {
        char *tmp = list_iter->filename;
        size_t tmp_len = strlen(tmp);
        char *s = realloc(final_string, final_len + tmp_len + 1); // +1 for '\0'
        if (s == NULL) {
            perror("realloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        final_string = s;
        memcpy(final_string + final_len, tmp, tmp_len + 1);
        final_len += tmp_len;
        list_iter = list_iter->next;
    }
    return final_string;
}
```

Maybe there is a **simple way to interpose a single character between two strings**?

Note: I know there's nothing wrong in repeating the same operation twice, I'm asking this question to know **if there is a better way** of doing so!

Comment: The "instead of" part, I suspect the order of the calls should be the opposite? Otherwise the slash will be at the end and not between the two strings.

Comment: As for a solution, why not simply write a function which does the two `strcat` calls, and returns the result? Then you can simply call that when and as needed. That will, probably, be the "better way" in the long run.

Comment: One suggestion: walk the list of items to concatenate twice: once to figure out how much space you'll need, then allocate that space.  Walk the list a second time to copy the data into the allocation. Not only is memory allocation an expensive operation (comparatively), it also generally means that the data gets copied again  by each `realloc()`.

Comment: Sounds like a job for snprintf(). Is there a reason not to use it?

Comment: IMO, OP is headed to a micro-optimization.  The time spent performing I/O certainly must exceed OP's good code of string concatenation - it is fast enough.

Comment: @chux At the same time it's complex and obfuscated, prone to introduce new errors, the opposite of elegant, and surely not the best way available to concatenate two strings with a delimiter in C.

Comment: `snprintf()`  might not be the best tool for repeated concatenation even if it might be a good tool for concatenating several strings in one go. repeated concatenation across several `snprinf()` calls requires some managing of the destination buffer manually, which can be error prone.  Specifically, the following pattern which I've seen used to append strings to a buffer is undefined behavior: `snprintf( dest, size-of-dest, "%s/%s", dest, newstring)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do sprintf:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char var1[] = "FileA.txt";
    char var2[] = "FileB.png";
    char var3[] = "FileC";

    char result[30];

    sprintf(result, "%s/%s/%s", var1, var2,var3);
    printf("result: %s\n", result);


    return 0;
}
```

And the result is like this:

```
result: FileA.txt/FileB.png/FileC
```

If you need, the variable result can be a pointer and allocate space based on your needs.

Comment: For security's sake, please **always** use `snprintf()`.

Comment: @Murphy `snprintf()` does have advantages over `sprintf()`, yet many application of it fail to check its return value.  By preventing overflow, yet  without acting on it, `snprintf()` trades one bad problem for another.  A substitution of `snprintf()` for `sprintf()` is insufficient for security, but can be a good 1st step.

Comment: Can you show how to add a variable number of items?  That's where using `sprintf()`/`snprintf()` get more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Burr mentioned in a comment to the question, it is best to walk the list/array twice. On the first pass, calculate the total length of the string needed. Next, allocate the memory needed for the entire string. On the second pass, copy the contents. Do not forget to account for, and append, the string-terminating nul byte (`\0`).

Consider the following example functions `dupcat()` and `dupcats()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *dupcat(const size_t count, const char *parts[])
{
    size_t  i, len = 0;
    char   *dst, *end;

    /* Calculate total length of parts. Skip NULL parts. */
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        len += (parts[i]) ? strlen(parts[i]) : 0;

    /* Add room for '\0'.
       We add an extra 8 to 15 '\0's, just because
       it is sometimes useful, and we do a dynamic
       allocation anyway. */
    len = (len | 7) + 9;

    /* Allocate memory. */
    dst = malloc(len);
    if (!dst) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dupcat(): Out of memory; tried to allocate %zu bytes.\n", len);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Copy parts. */
    end = dst;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        const char  *src = parts[i];
        /* We could use strlen() and memcpy(),
           but a loop like this will work just as well. */
        if (src)
            while (*src)
                *(end++) = *(src++);
    }

    /* Sanity check time! */
    if (end >= dst + len) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dupcat(): Arguments were modified during duplication; buffer overrun!\n");
        free(dst); /* We can omit this free(), but only in case of exit(). */
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Terminate string (and clear padding). */
    memset(end, '\0', (size_t)(dst + len - end));

    /* Done! */
    return dst;
}

char *dupcats(const size_t count, ...)
{
    size_t   i, len = 0;
    char    *dst, *end;
    va_list  args;

    /* Calculate total length of 'count' source strings. */
    va_start(args, count);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        const char  *src = va_arg(args, const char *);
        if (src)
            len += strlen(src);
    }
    va_end(args);

    /* Add room for end-of-string '\0'.
       Because it is often useful to know you have
       at least one extra '\0' at the end of the string,
       and we do a dynamic allocation anyway,
       we pad the string with 9 to 16 '\0',
       aligning 'len' to a multiple of 8. */
    len = (len | 7) + 9;

    /* Allocate memory for the string. */
    dst = malloc(len);
    if (!dst) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dupcats(): Out of memory; tried to allocate %zu bytes.\n", len);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Copy the source strings. */
    end = dst;
    va_start(args, count);
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        const char  *src = va_arg(args, const char *);
        /* We could use strlen() and memcpy() here;
           however, this loop is easier to follow. */
        if (src)
            while (*src)
                *(end++) = *(src++);
    }
    va_end(args);

    /* Sanity check. */
    if (end >= dst + len) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dupcats(): Arguments were modified during duplication; buffer overrun!\n");
        free(dst); /* We can omit this free(), but only in case of exit(). */
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Add end-of-string '\0' (filling the padding). */
    memset(end, '\0', dst + len - end);

    /* Done. */
    return dst;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *result;

    result = dupcat(argc - 1, (const char **)(argv + 1));
    printf("Arguments concatenated: '%s'.\n", result);
    free(result);

    result = dupcats(5, "foo", "/", "bar", "/", "baz");
    printf("Concatenating 'foo', '/', 'bar', '/', and 'baz': '%s'.\n", result);
    free(result);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Neither `dupcat()` nor `dupcats()` will ever return NULL: they will print an error message to standard error and exit, if an error occurs.

`dupcat()` takes an array of strings, and returns a dynamically allocated concatenated copy with at least eight bytes of nul padding.

`dupcats()` takes a variable number of pointers, and returns a dynamically allocated concatenated copy with at least eight bytes of nul padding.

Both functions treat NULL pointers as if they were empty strings. For both functions, the first parameter is the number of strings to concatenate.

(Since OP did not show the definitions of `struct file_list` or `struct file_node`, I did not bother to write a list-based version. However, it should be trivial to adapt from one of the two versions shown.)

---

In some cases, a variant that constructs a valid path from a fixed `base` part, with one or more relative file or directory names concatenated, and POSIXy `./` removed and `../` backtracked (but not out of `base` subtree), is very useful.

If carefully written, it allows the program to accept untrusted paths, relative to a specific subtree. (The combined paths are confined to that subtree, but symlinks and hardlinks can still be used to escape the subtree.)

One possible implementation is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

char *dynamic_path(const char *const subtree,
                   const size_t      parts,
                   const char       *part[])
{
    const size_t  subtree_len = (subtree) ? strlen(subtree) : 0;
    size_t        parts_len = 0;
    size_t        total_len, i;
    char         *path, *mark, *curr;

    /* Calculate the length of each individual part.
       Include room for a leading slash.
    */
    for (i = 0; i < parts; i++)
        parts_len += (part[i]) ? 1 + strlen(part[i]) : 0;

    /* Add room for the string-terminating '\0'.
       We're paranoid, and add a bit more padding. */
    total_len = ((subtree_len + parts_len) | 7) + 9;

    /* Allocate memory for the combined path. */
    path = malloc(total_len);
    if (!path) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* If the user specified a subtree, we use it as the fixed prefix. */
    if (subtree_len > 0) {
        memcpy(path, subtree, subtree_len);
        mark = path + subtree_len;
        /* Omit a trailing /. We enforce it below anyway. */
        if (parts > 0 && subtree_len > 1 && mark[-1] == '/')
            --mark;
    } else
        mark = path;

    /* Append the additional path parts. */
    curr = mark;
    for (i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
        const size_t  len = (part[i]) ? strlen(part[i]) : 0;
        if (len > 0) {
            /* Each path part is a separate file/directory name,
               so there is an (implicit) slash before each one. */
            if (part[i][0] != '/')
                *(curr++) = '/';
            memcpy(curr, part[i], len);
            curr += len;
        }
    }

    /* Sanity check. */
    if (curr >= path + total_len) {
        /* Buffer overrun occurred. */
        fprintf(stderr, "Buffer overrun in dynamic_path()!\n");
        free(path); /* Can be omitted if we exit(). */
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Terminate string (and clear padding). */
    memset(curr, '\0', (size_t)(path + total_len - curr));

    /* Cleanup pass.
       Convert "/foo/../" to "/", but do not backtrack over mark.
       Combine consecutive slashes and /./ to a single slash.
    */
    {
        char *src = mark;
        char *dst = mark;

        while (*src)
            if (src[0] == '/' && src[1] == '.' && src[2] == '.' && (!src[3] || src[3] == '/')) {
                src += 3; /* Skip over /.. */
                /* Backtrack, but do not underrun mark. */
                if (dst > mark) {
                    dst--;
                    while (dst > mark && *dst != '/')
                        dst--;
                }
                /* Never consume the mark slash. */
                if (dst == mark)
                    dst++;
            } else
            if (src[0] == '/' && src[1] == '.' && (!src[2] || src[2] == '/')) {
                src += 2; /* Skip over /. */
                if (dst == mark || dst[-1] != '/')
                    *(dst++) = '/';
            } else
            if (src[0] == '/') {
                src++;
                if (dst == mark || dst[-1] != '/')
                    *(dst++) = '/';
            } else
                *(dst++) = *(src++);

        /* Clear removed part. */
        if (dst < src)
            memset(dst, '\0', (size_t)(src - dst));
    }

    return path;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *path;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nUsage: %s PREFIX [ PATHNAME ... ]\n\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    path = dynamic_path(argv[1], argc - 2, (const char **)(argv + 2));
    if (!path) {
        fprintf(stderr, "dynamic_path(): %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("%s\n", path);
    free(path);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that I wrote the above version from scratch (and dedicate it to [public domain (CC0)](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)), so you should thoroughly test it before relying it on production use. (My intent is for it to be an useful example or basis, that will help you write your own implementation tailored to your needs.)

If you do find any bugs or issues in it, let me know in a comment, so I can verify and fix.